# Get list of EC2 instances with specific Tag and Value in Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scripting, boto3

How can I filter AWS instances using Tag and Value using `boto3`?

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_tags(
Filters=[{'Key': 'Owner', 'Value': 'user@example.com'}])
print(response)
```

Comment: The correct syntax looks like this.   @helloV just show a simple answer compare to client.describe_tags()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293366/what-is-the-correct-ways-to-write-boto3-filters-to-use-customise-tag-name

Answer (score 42):

You are using a wrong API. Use [describe_instances](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances)

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

custom_filter = [{
    'Name':'tag:Owner', 
    'Values': ['user@example.com']}]
    
response = client.describe_instances(Filters=custom_filter)
```

Comment: Thank You!!

with few modification i can able to achieve my requirement!

Answer (score 1):

Instance with tags and instances without tags can be retrieved as below
Can get all tags as below

```py
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',"us-west-1")
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
for instance in instances:
    if instance.tags != None:
        for tags in instance.tags:
        if tags["Key"] == 'Name' or tags["Key"] == 'Owner':
            if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
                instancename = tags["Value"]
            if tags["Key"] == 'Owner':
                owner = tags["Value"]
    else:
        instancename='-'
    print("Inastance Name - %s,  Instance Id - %s, Owner - %s " %(instancename,instance.id,owner))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Stop instances that are running and have no tags**

```
    import boto3
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',"ap-south-1")
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
    for instance in instances:
        #print(instance.tags)
        if instance.tags == None:
            print(instance.id)
            instance.stop()
        else:
            pass
```

**stop all running instances with a specific tag like tag key ='env'**

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',"ap-south-1")

# filter all running instances
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])

# Decleared list to store running instances
all_running_instances = []
specific_tag = 'env'  
for instance in instances:
    
    # store all running instances
     all_running_instances.append(instance)
        
    # Instances with specific tags
     if instance.tags != None:
         for tags in instance.tags:
             
            # Instances with tag 'env'
             if tags["Key"] == specific_tag:
                
                # Remove instances with specefic tags from all running instances
                 all_running_instances.remove(instance)
                    
#print(all_running_instances)
for specific in all_running_instances:
    print(specific)
    specific.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "resource" to get a list of the instances

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', "ap-southeast-2")
instances = ec2.instances.filter(
Filters=[
    {
        'Name': 'instance-state-name',
         'Values': [
            'running'
            ]
    },
    {
        'Name': 'tag:BusinessService',
        'Values': [
            '<insert tag>'
        ]
    },
]
```

)

Or use "client" to get a Dict

```
import boto3
ec2_cli = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
instances = ec2_cli.describe_instances(
Filters=[
    {
        'Name': 'instance-state-name',
         'Values': [
            'running'
            ]
    },
    {
        'Name': 'tag:BusinessService',
        'Values': [
            '<insert tag>'
        ]
    },
]
)
```

Comment: How does this improve on any of the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

**List instances that are running and have no tags**

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',"ap-south-1")
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
for instance in instances:
    #print(instance.tags)
    if instance.tags == None:
        print(instance.id)
        instance.stop()
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
        
    response = ec2_client.describe_tags(
        DryRun=False,
        Filters = [
            {
                'Name': 'resource-id',
                'Values': [
                    instance_ID,
                    ],
            },
            {
                'Name': 'key',
                'Values': ['key_of_the_tag_you_want_to_fetch']
                
            },
        ],
    )

tag_value = response['Tags'][0]['Value']
```

The variable `tag_value` will hold the value of tag with key
`['key_of_the_tag_you_want_to_fetch']`.
`instance_ID` is the Id of the instance you want to fetch the tag values from.

Answer (score -3):

boto3.client.describe_tags() is universal, but it is tedious to use. because you need to nest and specify the services, tag key name and tag values to filter . i.e.

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
filters =[
    {'Name': 'resource-type', 'Values': ['instance']},
    {'Name': 'Key', 'Values': ['Owner']},
    {'Name': 'Values', 'Values' : ['user@example.com']}
]
response = client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
```

As @helloV suggested, it is much easier to use describe_instances(). 
describe_tags is there to allow user to create function to traverse all the services tags.