# AWS Exporting DynamoDB Name to Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I’m trying to make a DynamoDB table, without having a name property in the .yml file so that it’s name by cloud formation, and export it’s name to python for access can I do that if so how?

My current idea is to to export the name as a ssm parameter but I’m not sure how.

Comment: Do you have the DynamoDB in a separate template.yml? Or was it created through the console?

Comment: @Deiv currently it’s created through the console. I’d like to transfer it over to the yml

Comment: Got it, will submit an answer in a minute, hard to format it through a comment

Comment: One more clarification point, you wish to only refer to the DB in the yml, or are you also considering creating it through the yml? Because the latter would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s how I ended up doing it:
Python:

```
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
resp = dict(ssm.get_parameter(Name='TableName', WithDecryption=False))
tableName = str(json.loads(json.dumps(resp['Parameter'],default=str))['Value'])
```

This is my cloudformation yaml file:

```
Resources:
  DynamoTable:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: A_Key
            AttributeType: "S"
          - AttributeName: Serial
            AttributeType: "S"
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: A_Key
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: Serial
            KeyType: RANGE
  DynamoTableParameter:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter”
    Properties:
      Name: "TableName”
      Type: String
      Value: !Ref DynamoTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tag it in the cloudformation template and get resources by tag in boto.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

custom_filter = [{
    'Name':'tag:Owner', 
    'Values': ['user@example.com']}]

response = client.describe_instances(Filters=custom_filter)
```

(This code is mostly copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48073016/10553976)

And this would correspond to tagging instances with the following:

```
Tags: 
  - 
    Key: "Owner"
    Value: "user@example.com"
```

Important: if you want to apply the tags to something other than the instances you would need to use a different method from the `describe` methods in the `rds` client.

Comment: I can’t do it this way, I think. I’m currently doing “boto3.resource(‘dynamodb’,region).Table(‘TableNameFromConfigINI’)” is there a solution that would stick in line with that code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is related to AWS CloudFormation, because you mention .yml file.

You can report the name in the output section of your cloudformation template, if your python function is declared in another template.  You can then use the `describe-stack` API or CLI to fetch the value from the output.

See :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html

If your python function is declared in the same template, you can just refer to your logical resource to get the name (as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html)

For example,

The section that creates the table

```
MyTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Description: your decsriptions
    Properties:
       ... your properties ...
```

The section that refers to it (here is an example with `AWS::AppSync::DataSource` but it applies to any type of resources

```
MyTableDataSource:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::DataSource 
    Properties:
      ...
      DynamoDBConfig:
        TableName:
          Ref: MyTable
        AwsRegion:
          Fn::Sub: ${AWS::Region}
```

or to get the table ARN in a IAM Policy

```
  Policies:
  - PolicyName: mypolicy
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        Resource:
        - Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - Fn::GetAtt:
              - MyTable
              - Arn
            - '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your reply to my comment, you wish to add the DynamoDB table into the yml file. If the table and the lambda are in the same .yml, then you can simply do !Ref YourTable, inside the Lambda Environment variables.

Something like this:

```
YourLambda:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Environment:
      Variables:
        YourTableName: !Ref YourTable
```

You will also need to add a policy attached to the Lambda, under Properties -> Policies, and you can reference the table name there the same way.

However, if you wish to reference the name without moving the DynamoDB instance inside the .yml file, then you have to make it a static reference by making an entry in Parameter Store, and then referencing it like so (making sure your CFN has access to ssm:getParameter):

```
YourLambda:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Environment:
      Variables:
        YourTableName: '{{resolve:ssm:/PATH/TO/TABLENAME:1}}'
```