# How to find all ec2 instances that are missing particular tag and value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, aws-lambda, boto3

Where can I find information about functions like .filter() or .all() in python boto3 library. I am using in the following code and it's displaying all the info correctly.

import boto3

def Diff(li1, li2): 
    return (list(set(li1)^set(li2)))

def my_handler(event, context):

```
Custom_filters_ec2=[{'Name': 'tag:Project','Values': ['Himanshu']},{'Name': 'tag:Email','Values': ['hima']},{'Name':'instance-state-name','Values':['running','stopped']}
     ]
Custom_filters_all=[{'Name': 'tag:Project','Values': ['Himanshu']},{'Name': 'tag:Email','Values': ['hima']},]     
ec2=boto3.resource('ec2',region_name='us-east-1')
ec=boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-east-1')

#Terminate Instances
valid_instance=ec2.instances.filter(Filters=Custom_filters_ec2)
all_instance=iec2.instances.all()
Untagged_Instances=[]
Untagged_Instances=Diff(valid_instance,all_instance)
for i in Untagged_Instances:
    i.terminate()

#Terminate Snapshot
valid_snapshots = ec2.snapshots.filter(Filters=Custom_filters_all).filter(OwnerIds=["XXXXXXXXXXXX"]).all()
all_snapshots = ec2.snapshots.filter(OwnerIds=["XXXXXXXXXXXX"]).all()
Untagged_snapshots=Diff(valid_snapshots,all_snapshots)
for i in Untagged_snapshots:
    i.delete()
```

but when i do this:

ec2.SecurityGroup.all() or ec2.SecurityGroup.filter(Filters=Custom_filters_all) i get the following error:

sg=ec2.SecurityGroup.filter(Filters=Custom_filters_all)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'filter'

I am looking to find documentation on how to use these functions like `.all()` or`.filter() or other functions that not documented.
 Why it works on ec2, snapshot but not when trying to get security group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct ways to write Boto3 filters to use customise tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293366/what-is-the-correct-ways-to-write-boto3-filters-to-use-customise-tag-name)

Comment: You code is not clear, what is inside `Custom_filters_all` ?  And why there is an extra `=instance` under `all_instance=instances=ec2.instances.all()` ?   In addition, `.all()` is common sense.

Comment: What are you actually wanting to do?

Comment: I am trying to find resources missing 2 tags and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

The boto3 EC2 [snapshot.filter() documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.snapshots) explains what filters are available.

However, rather than trying to create a filter, I would recommend that you obtain a *complete listing* of snapshots and then use Python to filter the list to what you desire. This can be done with some list comprehensions or simple `for` loops. Plus, the syntax is often a lot easier!